# I have a problem loading background-image in vue js's style tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuejs3

I tried everything in my vue app but even though I got the .html file to work with this, I can't get my app.vue file to load the background image. I have tried everything on the internet and it didn't work out. Let's get right to the problem.

```css
background-image: url("/@/components/images/Cover1.jpg");
```

this code doesn't do anything

I even added the background color and it works. everything except the image shows up. so I think it is because of the path. I tried everything from ~@/components/images/Cover1.jpg to /components/images/Cover1.jpg it doesn't even though when I use /components/images/Cover1.jpg and /@/components/images/Cover1.jpg vue js doesn't give me an error.

so here is the structure of the folders and files. the image i need is in the **images** folder

(2 errors are because of vetur bug and aren't linked with  tag)
I am styling the website from app.vue 's  tag

I also tried it in just a normal html and css file

```
folder:
    .images
    .index.html
    .styles.css
```

on this file structure and normal html css file

```
background-image: url("images/Cover1.jpg");
```

works
but app.vue one is problematic.
Please tell me what to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is truly embarrassing but the problem was the case...

image folder was with uppercase **"I"** but I wrote

`"~@/components/images/Cover1.jpg"`

instead of

`"~@/components/Images/Cover1.jpg"`

so it didn't load the image even though strangely enough it didn't give any errors

This was a silly thing to panic about... at least I contributed to the community -.-

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim Just a minor point: While it's good advice to tell OPs to delete their question if it's caused by a typo, or is not reproducible, it's not a good idea to do this *after* receiving answers. Even if it's a typo, that user has put some effort into writing an answer, and that needs to be taken into account.

Answer (score 0):

actually in vue static files should be in assets folder

```
background-image: url("~@/assets/images/Cover1.jpg");
```

still for your case try this path

```
background-image: url("~@/components/images/Cover1.jpg");
```

*note the tilda `~` key at the start